# HTTP Authentication issue in Test Cafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am performing automation of one site using TestCafe that has an http authentication, but I have to provide my email first in order land on http auth login page. This is one more layer before http auth login page.

When I login with my email id typically I should be asked to enter username and password in authentication box (http://testcafeurl/http://myhttpauthurl), but I do not. However, as soon as I remove the testcafe proxy url (http://testcafeurl/), webdriver shows the http authentication box!

So the issue is I have to remove the testcafe proxy url to make my http auth page running and I am not sure how to deal with testcafe proxy or bypass it to make my http auth page working perfectly.. Can anyone please suggest how can I deal with testcafe proxy url or what are the settings do I need to set for testcafe proxy?

Thank in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It's expected behavior. TestCafe injects the login information into HTTP request and browser is not show the 'HTTP authentification' dialog.

If your web site works wrongly with TestCafe and you can share an simple example with which it's possible to reproduce the problem, please create a separate [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe Github repository.